# How to remove duplicate values from a IList, c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an ilist with 6 records, something like this

1st Row

time
11:00

location:

Bangalore

2nd Row
time
11:00

Location
NULL

....

I have to eliminate the 2nd row
which has location null for the same time (11:00)

Like this, I will be having thousands of records, from which i need to eliminate this.

any solution ?

Comment: Is it always the adjacent rows?>

Comment: Are you looking to eliminate only records with a NULL location and duplicated time? What if the location is NULL but the time is not duplicated? And what about the records where the location is not null but the time is duplicated, or the location is different? Can you finish the sentence: *eliminate all records where the time is duplicated and...*

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like :

```
list.GroupBy(x=>x.Time)
    //from the grouped items select the first one that doesn't have an empty location - you'll have null here if none is found
    .Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault(y=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(y.Location)))
    .ToList()
```

Comment: +1, but the OP still needs to confirm what happens if a records has a different (but not null) value, if at all.

Comment: You are right, but I hope this would point him in a good direction. I would think that from this he should be able to come up with a solution that fits his scenario

Answer (score 1):

```
        public List<Row> GetRowsWthoutDuplicates(List<Row> source)
        {
            List<Row> filteredRows = new List<Row>(source);

            foreach (Row row in source)
            {
                if (!filteredRows.Exists(r => r.Time == row.Time))
                {
                    filteredRows.Add(row);
                }
            }

            return
                filteredRows;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might as well simply execute a "for" statement, and remove elements that don't qualify (with the step variable carefully "not-incremented" whenever a remove is performed).

Comment: And what if the dupe row with the null location occurs **before** the row that is to be kept?